# Easy way to extract print job payload from IPP packets

Tags: packet, packet-sniffers, ipp-protocol

Is there any tool existing or any shortcut that can be used to extract print job payload from IPP packets(captured via wireshark utility)?

Write now I'm manually inspecting/dissecting the packets byte per byte which is kind of excruciating especially with requests which spans several packet exchanges (HTTP Continue).

Thanks